# render component does not work when using v-for vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to make dynamic components fetched from an array. I tried using `<component></component>` to achieve this, but it didn't render anything. When I inspect it in the browser, the component is rendered like below:

```html
<test></test>
```

My code is,

```html
<template>
    <component v-for="(section, index) in compo" :key="section+index" v-bind:is="section" title="Gd" />
<template>

<script>
import Test from "@/Components/Test.vue";
export default {
  data() {
      return {
          compo: ['Test']
      }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried registering imported `Test` component in  `components` section of `export default`

Comment: the `:is` property on a `<component>` is used to determine which component to render. When statically importing a component (Test) you need to register it in the `components:{...}` property of your default export. 
In case you are going for a highly dynamic and potentially unpredictable components array, then you might want to read into dynamically importing components. When Components are dynamically imported, you don't need to register them. [Here is a blog about it, showing an example](https://medium.com/@pratikpatel_60309/dynamic-importing-component-templates-with-vue-js-78d2167db1e7)